# Bootstrap disable range datepicker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I want disable date with range. Example disable date from 2018-09-01 to 2018-09-20. What the best way do it with bootstrap datepicker?

Comment: What datepicker plugin are you using? There are multiple. Also have you tried any code yourself?

Comment: bootstrap datepicker @g